# Suppress successful insert statements or review errors on large inserts in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have ~130 SQL scripts that INSERT about ~750,000 records into an Oracle 12c database.

I have a master SQL that kicks all this off using this template:

```sql
set termout off
set echo off;

delete from table1;
@C:\Scripts\table1_DATA_TABLE.sql 
set termout on;
REM ---
REM completed table1_DATA_TABLE.sql
REM ---
set echo off;
set termout off;
commit;

<repeat for every script>
```

The issue is, I'm getting thousands of `1 row inserted.` and it's drowning out errors.  Is there a way I can suppress the successful INSERT notifications and only leave the errors?  Or, is there a way I can retrieve all the errors of a session/script ?

Comment: I would seriously question a design that inserts 750000 rows using insert statements in a script. How are those scripts generated ? Have you considered generating flat files (CSV) and load from those files using sql*loader ? Or declaring those files as external tables ? Both approaches are an order of magnitude faster than running a massive SQL script. Also safer, manageable and easier to run: both generate a log of errors and throw rejected rows in  separate files.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind, This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/179403).  Long story short, `expdp` and `impdp` are bugged and an RMAN restore runs into issues.  In my frustration, I scripted the database from sql\*developer without knowing about sql\*loader.  I'll look into it, thanks!  This is a one-off project so finding the perfect solution isn't as valuable.

Comment: "expdp and impdp are bugged". In what way ? Did you report that to Oracle Support ? What did they say ?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind, The particular 11g version I'm using has a bug with expdp and impdp.  The resolution on the Support Document is to upgrade the DB to a new major version.

Comment: What’s the bug number ? And what’s the big ? I’m surprised the only solution was to upgrade to a new release (what release ?). Generally bugs are fixed in regular patch sets or minor releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SET FEEDBACK OFF` suppresses the insert notifications.

See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG079).

You can also use `SET ERRORLOGGING` to log errors to a table of your choice. Again, [see the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG160).

Comment: Does exactly what I need.